# iOS notification receive: some can and the other can't

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsnotifications

I use a `UINavigationController` to control the view controller change.Supposing I push A1 and A2 one by one. Both A1 and A2 is the instance of my custom View Controller A.
A has registered a notification, and it will refresh the UI when it receive the notification.

My problem is :
when I post the notification in A2， and A2 can receive it.
However, when I pop to A1, there is no change in A1.

So could any one help me how to fix it?

BTW，the reason why I use notification is that I may push several instances of A,  and if any one posts the notification, the other instances in the stack also need to update.

Comment: use tag and set the tag value and check in if condition using tag id ...

Comment: But neither viewcontroller nor nsnotification has tag value...

Comment: In which `UIViewController` methods do you register/unregister for the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is your problem -
My problem is : when I post the notification in A2， and A2 can receive it. However, when I pop to A1, there is no change in A1.

When you pop to A1, then at that time A2 is deallocated and notification/listener that you have created there is also removed, so it won't respond to notification.
Now if you want A1 also to listen notification then you need to add observer in A1 as well.

Comment: No, I register each in the viewdidload. I find it OK after restarting the Xcode.Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but

Are you registering for the notifications in viewDidLoad: or viewDidAppear:?
Are you unregistering in viewDidUnload: or viewDidDisappear:?

Normally, using the appear/disappear methods to register for notifications is the best choice, since a view controller will only be interested in a notification while it's visible.

Whichever approach you use, though, make sure that your register and unregister calls are in matching UIViewController methods.

Comment: Are you sure the view controller will be notified only it is visible?

Comment: It will receive no matter it is invisible or not

Comment: No, what I mean is that, if you're calling addObserver: in viewDidLoad:, then make sure you're calling removeObserver: in viewDidUnload:, not in viewDidDisappear:.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange it can receive the notifications after I restart the Xcode(4.3.1 (4E1019)).

thanks for your guys' help.

BTW, the object will receive the notification if it is not deallocated.